# Button that appears when a Chrome Extension is enabled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, button, google-chrome-extension

I would like to create a Chrome Extension that when enabled, a button will appear in a certain website. It is very similar to the Youtube Download Button extension in which when enabled a "download" button would appear somewhere in youtube. I also tried studying the codes used in that extension but I am new to javascript so I can't understand the codes itself.
Thanks you very much to whoever can answer my question :))

Comment: Please add some tries you did ;)

Comment: Well, I haven't really tried yet 'cause I am still in the research stage. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in your [manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest) and allow your script to run on particular pages using [matches](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

```
 "content_scripts": [
 {
   "matches": ["http://www.example.com/*", "https://www.example.com/*"],
   "css": ["yourCSS.css"],
   "js": ["yourScript.js"]
 }
]
```

Now your content script will be injected by your extension to your intended page.

Now, in `yourScript.js`, insert a button to the page with the `source` to be downloaded.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Im'ma try it later. :)

Comment: @user3816302 : Do tell if it helped.

Comment: I really am a noob here. XD
What do you mean "page with the source to be downloaded."? Thanks :))

Comment: @user3816302 : By source I mean the `source location` of the `video` on the `server`. You will have to find the location of the video in the page source code.

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was not that clear :)
I was referring to a button that would link users to another page.